# @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import TeleBot

bot: TeleBot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    send_mess = f"<b> Кчау, {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}!</b>"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stor=True)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\бот\bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Пробовал переустанавливать библиотеку Telebot с последующей перезагрузкой, не помогло.

Comment: Как пробовали переустанавливать?

Answer (score 1):

Переустановите библиотеку следующим образом:

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip install -U pytelegrambotapi
```

Comment: теперь выдает такую ошибку
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\бот\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telebot import TeleBot
ImportError: cannot import name 'TeleBot' from 'telebot' (unknown location)

Answer (score 0):

Скачай репозиторий с гит хаба https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI
и установи с него эту библиотеку но не забудь удалить её командой pip uninstall telebot

Comment: ошибка по-прежнему имеется